# Handling multiple controllers for same template in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, structure

I have a requirement wherein a single page contains lot of data. All these data are though different but needs to be displayed in one page only (with vertical scroll).

I have made various collapsible divs on my page and they are controlled usig `ng-if` for avoiding too much of DOM.

Initially for prototype, I had JS logics for all these divs in one controller. However, now I am following a different approach wherein I want one controller for the page and various child controller for the collapsible divs.

I kept one object each for a div in page controller and made several other controller on my main module (app.js). I expect each of them to be child of `pageCtrl` and as such I should be accessing data for each div in 'pageCtrl`.

However, this is not working. No errors though on consoles, but no divs are visible.

My structure is as:

```
<body ng-app ="mainModule">
 <div ng-controller ="pageCtrl">
    <div ng-controller = "collapse1Ctrl" ng-include="collapse1.tpl" ng-if="collapse1reqd">
<div ng-controller = "collapse2Ctrl" ng-include="collapse2.tpl" ng-if="collapse2reqd">
<div ng-controller = "collapse3Ctrl" ng-include="collapse3.tpl" ng-if="collapse3reqd">
<div ng-controller = "collapse4Ctrl" ng-include="collapse4.tpl" ng-if="collapse4reqd">
<div ng-controller = "collapse5Ctrl" ng-include="collapse5.tpl" ng-if="collapse5reqd">

</div>
```

JS is like:

```
angular.module("mainModule", []);
angular.module("mainModule").controller("pageCtrl", pageCtrlFn);
angular.module("mainModule").controller("collaspse1Ctrl", collaspse1CtrlFn);
angular.module("mainModule").controller("collaspse2Ctrl", collaspse2CtrlFn);
angular.module("mainModule").controller("collaspse3Ctrl", collaspse3CtrlFn);
angular.module("mainModule").controller("collaspse4Ctrl", collaspse4CtrlFn);
angular.module("mainModule").controller("collaspse5Ctrl", collaspse5CtrlFn);
```

Rest assured, all templates and conditions are at correct places.

Since my code as such is too large, I am avoiding to post it currently. May be I will post a similar fiddle soon.

But currently I wonder if is there any problem with having such a structure at all ??

Comment: No not at all ! But I recommend you to use 'controller As' syntax for your approach as you have nested controllers.So to avoid clustering of scopes objects that syntax would help you to maintain clean scope. Here is the Angular doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Comment: You mean to use the same approach but with an `alias` for each controller ?

Comment: Exactly !That would keep your code and scope clean as they are nested way much.

Comment: @Angular_10 I tried something of this sort. However, for Ctrl1 if I need some data and I make a API call in Ctrl1. How do I access this data in Ctrl2/Ctrl3. I see this is a basic parent-sibling thing. But somehow I am stuck at passing data among all these siblings. Is having a service the only way here ?

Comment: Hmm ..that's a nice question ! this is where prototypical inheritance comes into act.So to access parent controller scope properties in child controller you need to follow (.) Dot notation while naming your scope objects.For example $scope.obj.parentObj = 'Ctrl1 scope';

Comment: Sorry..but I didn't get your point

Comment: Hope this link helps you https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: I think my question was not clear. Basically I have one `scope` in which I had lot of DOM. To just modularise the DOM, I broke this DOM into several templates and used them as `ng-include` in original one. Additionally I wrapped each DOm in one controller each. Now I get the data for each these controller in my parent controller. I somehow want to pass the relevant data to each of these different controller and use it in respective templates. Also I want to have the hold of everything in my parent controller for saving data and other operations

Comment: May be using `controllerAs` is causing problem by creating isolated scopes

Comment: Can you create a sample plunker of your current problem that would help us solve the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123714/discussion-between-saurabh-tiwari-and-angular-10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OP's question and the problem's faced here's an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/OaJhhZeNEnCczDxyJRci?p=preview) demo on how nested controllers work and how the scope behaves.

HTML looks like

```
<body ng-app="scopeInheritance">
<div class="spicy">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>
        <p>{{display.showName}} - {{age}} --> New Age - {{display.age}}</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">

        <button ng-click="resetTime()">CHANGE</button>
        <div ng-controller="ChildController">
            <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>
            <button ng-click="setTime()">SET</button>
            <input type="text" ng-model="display.showName"> Age - {{age}}
            <input type="text" ng-model="age">
            <button ng-click="setAge()">Change Age</button>
            <div ng-controller="GrandChildController">
                <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS looks like below

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('scopeInheritance', []);
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.timeOfDay = 'morning';
  $scope.files ='';
  $scope.name = 'Nikki';
  $scope.display={};
  $scope.display.showName ='Vikram';
  $scope.age ='20';
 // $scope.display.age ='20';
  $scope.resetTime = function(){
     $scope.timeOfDay = 'chaged day';
   };

}]);
myApp.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Mattie';
   $scope.$parent.timeOfDay ='';
   $scope.setTime = function(){
     $scope.timeOfDay = 'new day';
   };
   $scope.setAge = function(){
     $scope.display.age ='25';
   };
}]);
myApp.controller('GrandChildController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.timeOfDay = 'evening';
  $scope.name = 'Gingerbread Baby';
}]);
})(window.angular);
```

This example is an extension of Angular Js org nested controllers doc's based example.

Comment: Thanks man.. I basically was under the impression that each child shares the same scope as that of parent. However, the case is that its a prototypically inherited scope. So each child will make its property on its own scope unless its a property on a object of parent scope. Hope what I got is right. !!

Comment: Yes exactly now you understood it perfectly ! Glad I could help you ..cheers ! :)

Comment: By the way..the interesting thing is TCS guys helping each other beyond TCS

Answer (score 0):

Better to wrap all your templates and controllers into components and hide them from outside controller

```
<component1 ng-if="req1"></component1>
<component2 ng-if="req2"></component2>
<component3 ng-if="req3"></component3>
```

and use ControllerAs of course.

Comment: I hope by component you mean a directive in Angular and nothing from Angular2 Components